# I get this error: RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

While trying to run my discord bot, I get this error. 
Here is my code.

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')


@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def ping(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel("826609837600931861")
    await channel.send('h')


client.login('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

The Error:

`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.login' was never awaited`

Answer (score 1):

`client.login` is a coroutine. You can run it with `asyncio`

```py
import asyncio
#other code here

asyncio.run(client.login('token'))
```

### References:

- [Client.login](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=login#discord.Client.login)
- [Running coros](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

Comment: Hello, I am confused how to implement this into my code. How would I be able to use asyncio for this.

Comment: Simple, just change the last line, you need asyncio to run a coroutine if you aren't inside a async function

Answer (score 1):

You can user client.run() this will do all the eventloop thingies for you.

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')


@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def ping(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel("826609837600931861")
    await channel.send('h')


client.run('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but my goal is for the bot to send a message in a specific channel, and then go offline, how would I be able to do this.

Comment: take a look at the on_ready event. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=ready#discord.on_ready you can send a message there and close the bot with .close()

Comment: @JoeJay, that actually belongs in a separate question, your question was that you were unable to run the coroutine, and I think both the answers answered that correctly. Please frame your question and your intentions precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change:

```
client.login('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

To:

```
client.run('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

Comment: hi @AcidOP   this solves the issue, could you might say why ? or link the docu of the function client.run ? thanks

Comment: @t2solve [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=run#discord.Client.run) you go